# kernel:[ 15.642879] Code: 91059283 52800020 1400016f 17ffffa0 (d4210000) - Error when booting (Oracle cloud instance)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

When I boot on my oracle cloud instance (running on the lastest ubuntu), since I installed the last update, my machine show me the error :

```
Message from syslogd@ampere at Jun  9 18:45:43 ...
 kernel:[   15.642879] Code: 91059283 52800020 1400016f 17ffffa0 (d4210000)
```

And then 2min later, my machine shut down.
I don't even have time to type any command while I booting. (only for 1 or 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by typing : `sudo systemctl disable docker.service docker.socket`
and then on restart by update with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get full-upgrade`.